# Mongodb official image errno:111 Connection refused when trying to create replicaset

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongodb-replica-set

I am trying to use the official MongoDB docker image to create a 3-set replication cluster inside a single container.

following [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set-for-testing/) official guide I created the following dockerfile:

> ```
>   FROM mongo:3.2
>     RUN mkdir -p /srv/mongodb/rs0-0 /srv/mongodb/rs0-1 /srv/mongodb/rs0-2
>     CMD mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /srv/mongodb/rs0-0 --replSet rs0 --smallfiles --oplogSize 128 &
>     CMD mongod --port 27018 --dbpath /srv/mongodb/rs0-1 --replSet rs0 --smallfiles --oplogSize 128 &
>     CMD mongod --port 27019 --dbpath /srv/mongodb/rs0-2 --replSet rs0 --smallfiles --oplogSize 128 &
>     CMD mongo --port 27017 --eval 'rs.initiate({_id: "rs0",members: [{_id: 0,host: "localhost:27017"}]})'
>     CMD mongo --port 27017 --eval "printjson(rs.conf())"
>     CMD mongo --port 27017 --eval 'rs.add("localhost:27018")'
>     CMD mongo --port 27017 --eval 'rs.add("localhost:27019")'
>     CMD mongo --port 27017 --eval "printjson(rs.status())"
> ```

but when I run it, I get the following error:

> ```
>   MongoDB shell version: 3.2.9
>     connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27017/test
>     2016-09-04T06:53:06.664+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
>     2016-09-04T06:53:06.664+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
>     connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:231:14
>     @(connect):1:6
> ```

```
    exception: connect failed
```

When I run the original mongo image and try to run the same CMDs I don't get the same.

I tried adding `USER root` to the Dockerfile but that didn't help at all.

What can I do to make this work?

**UPDATES**

- Also tried to create an image starting from `ubuntu`, same result
- Well, this seems to be some sort of docker file permission issues. When I moved the code to a bash script and run it from there, everything worked fine. this is not an answer to why this happens but a solution if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Your dockerfile isn't working because you've put in more than one CMD, which is invalid.

The [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/cmd) says:

> There can only be one CMD instruction in a Dockerfile. If you list more than one CMD then only the last CMD will take effect.